# Constructing a set by iteratively taking powersets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

### Short question

Is this definition correct (in the sense that it defines a set)?

> Let A be defined inductively as the smallest set such that:
>
> - $ \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \subseteq A$
> - if $X \subseteq A$, then $2^X \subseteq A$

### A few ideas

The "defined inductively" part seems to be ok to me since it could be seen as the least fixpoint of the function
$$
F(X) = \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \cup 2^X
$$
which is monotone in $X$. But does a non-naive set theory (maybe ZFC?) admit such a definition? Or would this definition, if admitted, lead to some paradoxes (like [Russel's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox))? If that definition works, what would be the domain of $F$ (because it cannot be the "set of all sets").

I would approach it this way: $F$ could be a function on the *class* of all sets. But can we then take its fixpoint? Does the Knaster-Tarski theorem work outside the realm of sets, $\mu F$ then being a class? If so, we could then try to prove $\mu F$ to be a set from the ZFC axioms. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You run into trouble: you have $A\subseteq A$, so $A\in\wp(A)\subseteq A$ and hence $A\in A$, contradicting the [axiom of regularity (foundation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).